Client Side Screenshot In MVC 4 C#
We've created a stream using navigator.mediadevices.getdisplaymedia which ask permissions to take a screenshot.
All code written in _layout page and it's working, but there is problem, it asking for the (same) permission every time when opening a new menu.
Is there is any way to avoid the fact that the permissions need to be approved every time, or any other solution to take screenshot in mvc 4 c#
For this issue i was tried to store stream details in session, searched another solution to take screenshot, also searched to avoid _layout page load only once, but proper solution not found.
My Code:->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        var videoStream;
                
        function handleStreamEnded(stream) {
                        
            stream.getVideoTracks()[0].addEventListener('ended', () => {
                requestScreenCapturePermission();
            });
                
            var strm = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];

        };
                
        async function requestScreenCapturePermission() {
             
            try {
                
                videoStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
                    video: {
                        mediaSource: 'screen',
                        displaySurface: "monitor"
                    },

                    preferCurrentTab: false,

                    //selfBrowserSurface: "exclude",

                    //surfaceSwitching: "include",

                    monitorTypeSurfaces: "include",

                });

                handleStreamEnded(videoStream);
                                
                return true;

            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error capturing screen:', error);

                return false;
            }
        };
                
        async function takeScreenShot(sender) {
             
            try {
                if (!videoStream) {
                     requestScreenCapturePermission();
                }
                  
                var video = document.createElement('video');

                video.srcObject = videoStream;

                await video.play();
                    
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

                canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
                canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
                    
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    
                var base64image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("SaveScreenCapture", "ScreenCapture")',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { base64string: base64image },
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) { },
                    error: function () { alert('Error') }
                });
                        
                IWannaChat.server.send(sender, base64image);

            }
            catch (error) {
                console.error('Error capturing screen:', error);
            }
        };
        
        $(document).ready(function () {

            if(!videoStream)
            {
               requestScreenCapturePermission();
            }

            var hub = $.connection.myChatHub;

            hub.client.takeScreenShot = function (sendCnnId, sender) {
                                
                if (!videoStream)
                    requestScreenCapturePermission();
                 
                takeScreenShot(sender);
            };

        });

    </script>


Could you also update the question to use regular sentence casing, instead if Title Casing,  Where Each Word Starts With A Capital Letter?
